# How can I make this functions recursive?

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to return the value of all-coordinates, the functions get-initial-state and get-final-state
return cons (1.1) and ((-rows 2).(- columns 2)) respectively.

```
(define (generate-coordinates rows columns)
  (define all-coordinates (for*/list ([i rows][j columns]) (cons i j)))
  (let ([initial-state (get-initial-state)]
        [end-state (get-end-state rows columns)])
  (remove initial-state (remove end-state all-coordinates))))
```

The result should be something like this:
'((0 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 2) (0 . 3) (0 . 4) (1 . 0) (1 . 2) (1 . 3) (1 . 4)
As you can see, the pair (1 . 1) is removed as well as the one with values (rows-2 . columns-2).
The format has to be a list of pairs.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)
```

Let me first start out by lifting out `all-coordinates` as a function and writing out `get-initial-state` and `get-end-state` functions:

```
(define (generate-coordinates rows columns)
  (let ([initial-state (get-initial-state)]
        [end-state (get-end-state rows columns)])
    (remove initial-state (remove end-state (all-coordinates rows columns)))))

(define (all-coordinates rows columns)
  (for*/list ([i rows] [j columns])
    (cons i j)))


(define (get-initial-state)
  (cons 1 1))


(define (get-end-state rows columns)
  (cons (- rows 2) (- columns 2)))
```

Realising that the `for*/list` is like recurring on the natural numbers - rows and columns, we can rewrite the all-coordinates recursively. Recurring on row-1 or cols-1 until they reach 0, and combining into a single list:

```
(define (all-coordinates.v2 rows cols)
  (cond [(= rows 0) empty]
        [else (append (all-coordinates.v2 (sub1 rows) cols)
                      (row-coordinates (sub1 rows) cols))]))

(define (row-coordinates thisrow cols)
  (cond [(= cols 0) empty]
        [else (append  (row-coordinates thisrow (sub1 cols))
                       (list (cons thisrow (sub1 cols))))]))
```

Finally, tests:

```
(check-equal? (all-coordinates 3 3) (all-coordinates.v2 3 3))
(check-equal? (all-coordinates 0 0) (all-coordinates.v2 0 0))
(check-equal? (all-coordinates 1 0) (all-coordinates.v2 0 1))
(check-equal? (all-coordinates 2 3) (all-coordinates.v2 2 3))
(check-equal? (all-coordinates 3 2) (all-coordinates.v2 3 2))
(check-equal? (all-coordinates 2 2) (all-coordinates.v2 2 2))
```